# Dual Monitors with DisplayPort and DVI-D

Tags: multiple-monitors, port, dvi, displayport

I have a [Dell Optiplex 990](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/optiplex-990/pd?&ST=dell%20optiplex%20990&dgc=ST&cid=76590&lid=1971445&acd=shdJHKmF1,17346152740,901qz26673) with an [AMD Radeon HD 6670 graphics card](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/amd-radeon-hd-6000/hd-6670/pages/amd-radeon-hd-6670-overview.aspx). I would like to use my two [Dell UltraSharp U2711 monitors](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=224-8284&dgc=ST&cid=72662&lid=1838870&acd=spla_pl_dhsea:028093,,901pdb6671) in a dual configuration with my computer.  Both monitors have a single DisplayPort port and two DVI-D connectors. The graphics card has one Displayport and one DVI-D. The motherboard on the computer also has a DisplayPort and DVI-D wired directly into it.

My first guess for how to do this is to connect both monitors directly to the graphics card, one via DisplayPort, one via DVI-D. However, **is it possible to connect the two monitors to each other via DVI-D and one to the computer via DisplayPort? Am I correct to assume that I should not use the port wired into the motherboard?**

What is the best way to configure the cables for connecting the monitors to the computer?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ATI 6000 series supposed supports DisplayPort spec 1.2 which supports Daisy-Chaining. However, I'm not sure how it would connect in your case as each of your monitors only contains a single DP connector.

You're probably best off using one DP and one DVI connection.

Comment: There are not currently any MONITORS on the market that support daisy chaining, though.  (Certainly not the U2711 since it doesn't have enough ports anyway).  AMD has had this support for a while but Nvidia hasn't bothered yet for the most part, and this is why - nobody's missing it yet.

Answer (score -1):

use dell adaptor: connects via displayport + 1 x usb (to power it) 
 other end is a triple dvi monitor connector .
Cost £80 ish amazon called a dell mmh11 multi monitor hub
Dell part no mmh11 64xhk